# Ideal payments with stripe laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

So I followed this tutorial and got stripe working with credit cards:
http://felicianoprochera.com/simple-payments-with-stripe-and-laravel/

Now I want to have an option to make ideal payments.
So in the stripe docs I found this:
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal

It says I have to create a source.
If I get it right: the order controller is only fixed on charging and the index.blade.php got the code to trigger the charge.

So how can I change this code to create the source and charge after it?

I found this link, but dont know how to put this all together:
https://github.com/ob-stripe/example-stripe-php-ideal/blob/master/web/index.php

Sorry for the noob question, but I can't find proper ideal tutorials anywhere and my skills are not good enough to make these steps work :(

Thanks in advance!